# Simple Deform animation isn't playing when exported as FBX

Tags: animation, modifiers, objects, export

I'm trying to animate one element of a model bending by using the Simple Deform modifier. I've got the animation looking how I want it in Blender, but when I export the object as an FBX and load it into Marmoset, the modifier doesn't animate. Iv'e tested exporting animations that use the location and rotation keyframes, and those work just fine.

Comment: I believe `.pc2` and `.mdd` files support an animated mesh data, addons for both are included with blender. Also if marmoset supports alembic you could try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FBX file format does not support deformations.  You will need to find a different way to export that data.